# Fetch from hash with either Singular or Plural

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following input hash in my ruby code

```
 my_hash = { include: 'a,b,c' }
```

(or)

```
 my_hash = { includes: 'a,b,c' }
```

Now I want the fastest way to get 'a,b,c'

I currently use

```
 def my_includes
   my_hash[:include] || my_hash[:includes]
 end
```

But this is very slow because it always checks for :include keyword first then if it fails it'll look for :includes. I call this function several times and the value inside this hash can keep changing. Is there any way I can optimise and speed up this? I won't get any other keywords. I just need support for :include and :includes.

Comment: We may be able to help more if you could explain the problem in greater detail. For example, do you control changes to `my_hash` or is that under external control? If the latter, would if be helpful to keep a record of whether `:include` or `:includes` occurred most recently? For example, if `:includes` occurred last you could first try `my_hash[:includes]`, in the hopes that the key has not yet changed to `:includes`, in which case a non-`nil` value would be returned.

Comment: Define "slow." While I could provide a solution to search to keys based on a regex or pattern matching, I can't see how that's actually any faster than a C-speed short-circuit evaluation. Did you actually benchmark this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Caveats and Considerations

First, some caveats:

1. You tagged this Rails 3, so you're probably on a very old Ruby that doesn't support a number of optimizations, newer Hash-related method calls like [#fetch_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch_values) or [#transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21), or [pattern matching](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html) for structured data.
2. You can do all sorts of things with your Hash lookups, but none of them are likely to be faster than a Boolean short-circuit when assuming you can be sure of having only one key or the other at all times.
3. You haven't shown any of the calling code, so without benchmarks it's tough to see how this operation can be considered "slow" in any general sense.
4. If you're using Rails and not looking for a pure Ruby solution, you might want to consider [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveModel/Dirty) to only take action when an attribute has changed.

### Use Memoization

Regardless of the foregoing, what you're probably missing here is some form of memoization so you don't need to constantly re-evaluate the keys and extract the values each time through whatever loop feels slow to you. For example, you could store the results of your Hash evaluation until it needs to be refreshed:

```
attr_accessor :includes

def extract_includes(hash)
  @includes = hash[:include] || hash[:includes]
end
```

You can then call `#includes` or `#includes=` (or use the *@includes* instance variable directly if you like) from anywhere in scope as often as you like without having to re-evaluate the hashes or keys. For example:

```
def count_includes
  @includes.split(?,).count
end

500.times { count_includes }
```

The tricky part is basically knowing if and when to update your memoized value. Basically, you should only call #extract_includes when you fetch a new Hash from somewhere like ActiveRecord or a remote API. Until that happens, you can reuse the stored value for as long as it remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a modified hash that has both keys `:include` and `:includes` with the same values:

```
my_hash = { include: 'a,b,c' }
```

```
my_hash.update(my_hash.key?(:include) ? { includes: my_hash[:include] } :
  { include: my_hash[:includes] })
  #=> {:include=>"a,b,c", :includes=>"a,b,c"}
```

This may be fastest if you were using the same hash `my_hash` for multiple operations. If, however, a new hash is generated after just a few interrogations, you might see if both the keys `:include` and `:includes` can be included when the hash is constructed.